# Safely and efficiently calling a TCP/IP sockets service from a Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, sockets, tcp

I have a legacy TCP/IP based service that runs as a windows service. I need to create a standard web service that receives client requests over HTTP, communicates with the legacy back-end TCP/IP service, and responds to the client based on the response from the back end TCP service. Put simply, the web service will need to handle bi-directional communication with the back-end TCP/IP service, but only at most one send/receive per web service request.

I will be using WCF, C#, and the standard .NET framework to handle creation of the web service, and to make TCP connections to the back end.

In this scenario, is it typically safer and more efficient to enable WCF to allow cross-request shared objects by changing it's instance mode to single and maintain a connection pool with persistent open connections to the back-end TCP/IP server, or is it better to just create a TCP/IP connection from the web service to the back end TCP/IP service each time the web service receives a request that requires this and close it after it responds?

Comment: Does that TCP/IP based server has connection pooling? And how fast the average request processes?

Comment: The served will not be a bottleneck and the average request processing time will vary, but doesn't really matter because overhead is overhead and that's what I'm seeking to eliminate even if it's relatively small against some requests. Typically though, most requests will be fairly short running.